# How to always let heroku run a command on deployment for a django project?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was working on a django project. The Procfile is the place that heroku always looks on before deployment.
Currently it is configured this way and it works all fine.

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn project_folder.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

This means it runs collectstatic command every time I make any changes in my project and deploy it on server. Can the same thing apply to run a background task? This background task needs to run automatically after my project is deployed.
python manage.py process_tasks is what I type in my command to trigger this background_task in django on my local server. So, would something like this help invoke it the same way as python manage.py collectstatic is (that is collecting all static files from my static folder)?

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; python manage.py process_tasks; gunicorn project_folder.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the `release` process type? (as mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase))

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn project_folder.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
release: python manage.py process_tasks
```

It should run the release command after deployment is complete.

Comment: I partly got answer to my question however what I failed to make understand from my question was that I want to run this command after deployment but it will run indefinitely. If I mention it in release it the release phase goes on forever and my project is never deployed. So, unfortunately this approach does not work @Bihan Viranga